# How can I add 45 degree line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my ggplot code:

```
ggplot(data_fig, aes(x=money$diff_tr, y=av_change))+ geom_point()
```

and the output is:

[image: output]

but I want to add 45 degree line starting from the -15. Can you help me to add this line? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a line that is actually 45 degrees as printed on the plot? Because x and y are on entirely different scales here but normally a "45 degree line" implies you want a slope coefficient=1.

Comment: I want to apply a line according to this data. like instead of starting at 0, it's a 45 degree line starting at -15. I hope i could explain.

Comment: Try adding `geom_abline(slope = 1)` But in any case it would be better to make your question reproducible with data and code: [MRE]

Comment: When I add a 45 degree line, all the data shifts to the right. Can't we put a fixed 45 degree line without playing the data? It shouldn't have anything to do with data, it's just a classic fixed line starting at -15.

Comment: by the way I tried what you said but it created almost straight line starting from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter the scales for x or y, a 45 degrees line can be added like this.

```
p + geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(-Inf, Inf), y = c(-Inf, Inf)), aes(x, y))
```

Answer (score 3):

A 45 degree line will not stay at 45 degrees in ggplot unless you have a fixed aspect ratio in your plotting window. I *think* what you want is a line that goes from the bottom left at 15 to the top right of the plot.

I have had to approximate your data here from your plot to get an example to show you:

```r
p <- ggplot(data_fig, aes(x=money$diff_tr, y=av_change)) + 
  geom_point()
  
p + geom_abline(slope = diff(layer_scales(p)$y$get_limits()) /
                  diff(layer_scales(p)$x$get_limits()),
                intercept = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, did you just guess the input data? Do you mind sharing the data?